# Mix several IEnumerable<T> feeds into one in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable, enumerable

I often need to perform action where I have `IEnumerable<T> A`, `IEnumerable<T> B` and I want to create `IEnumerable<T> C` where C will take 2T from A, then 1T from B, then again 2T from A, then 1T from B and so on - AABAABAAB...

Is there some language construct in C#, maybe some LINQ expression to acomplish that easily.

For now i wrote small helper class that enables me this:

`var C = EnumerableMixer(new int[]{2, 1}, A, B)`:

```
    public class EnumerableMixer<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        int[] Quantity;
        IEnumerable<T>[] Args;

        public EnumerableMixer(int[] quantity, params IEnumerable<T>[] args)
        {
            this.Quantity = quantity;
            this.Args = args;
            if (quantity.Length != args.Length)
                throw new NotImplementedException("Quantity must have same length as number of args!");
        }

        IEnumerable<T> Mix
        {
            get
            {
                var available = new List<int>(Quantity.Length);
                var enumerators = new List<IEnumerator<T>>(Quantity.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < Quantity.Length; ++i)
                {
                    available.Add(i);
                    enumerators.Add(Args[i].GetEnumerator());
                }
                while (available.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < available.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        var id = available[i];
                        for (int j = 0; j < Quantity[id]; ++j)
                        {
                            if (enumerators[id].MoveNext())
                                yield return enumerators[id].Current;
                            else
                            {
                                available.RemoveAt(i);
                                i--;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        #region IEnumerable<T> Members

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return Mix.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable Members

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: What should happen if one enumeration is completely enumerated before the other? For example: A= {1,4,8,9}, B={0,1,2,3,4,5,6}. Should it be {1,4,0,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6} or {1,4,0,8,9,1} or even {1,4,0,8,9} or throw an exception?

Comment: What should happen if one enumeration doesn't contain a number of element multiple of the mix quantity? For example: A= {1,4,8}, B={0,1,2,3,4,5,6}. Should it be {1,4,0,8,1,2,3,4,5,6} or {1,4,0,8} or throw an exception?

Comment: Do you know about [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)? The way you talk about mixing the various "feeds" just feels so Rx to me. In Rx, there are various operators for combining IObservable sequences together seamlessly that should really be of use to you. I personally would seriously consider it in your case.

Comment: @CédricBignon Your questions are good, i think that for general solution we must have enum with several options how to handle enumeration ends.

Comment: @julealgon i think rx are not that helpful here

Answer (score 2):

A little bit longer solution would be:

```
    public IEnumerable<TValue> Mix<TValue>(IEnumerable<TValue> a, IEnumerable<TValue> b)
    {
        var aEnumerator = a.GetEnumerator();
        var bEnumerator = b.GetEnumerator();

        while (true)
        {
            if (!aEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield break;
            }

            yield return aEnumerator.Current;

            if (!aEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield break;
            }

            yield return aEnumerator.Current;

            if (!bEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield break;
            }

            yield return bEnumerator.Current;
        }
    }
```

This solution does not create unnecessary objects. If you are not familiar with the yield keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted (unless I've missed something), it's what I was going to suggest before I saw OP had implemented a much more complicated version.

Comment: I didn't dw your answer but it has no option to set 2-1 ratio as function argument, thats why it is more simple. Also it will break when one of them finishes, while mine will finish them all, not sure which is better. Notice that mine solution suports combination of more than 2 ienumerables.

Comment: @watbywbarif Then you should have explained that in your requirements, instead of just saying that you wanted to have enumerables in which one iterates 2 objects for every one of the other.

Comment: Sorry but this was only example, if you look at question it is clearly stated several, and also from my helper class you an see that i enabled several enumeratios and custom number of samples from each.

Comment: Also i did't say that this solution is bad, it works OK for my case, but at the end when you are comparing two solutions in the case thath both work correctly you will take some extra considerations like which will perform better, which is more general, or ... I agree that there is no need to use OP here like i did in my solution because static function will perform better and code is shorter and simpler, but that is very easy to change.

Answer (score 2):

### Version 1

This is based on adhie's solution. It takes the ratio into consideration and finishes the both sequences fully before exiting the method. The `flag` is used to keep track if last loop has yielded anything. When `flag` is false, both sequences are depleted.

```
public IEnumerable<T> Mix<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequenceA, IEnumerable<T> sequenceB, int ratioA, int ratioB)
{
    var etorA = sequenceA.GetEnumerator();
    var etorB = sequenceB.GetEnumerator();
    bool flag = true;

    while(flag)
    {
        flag = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < ratioA && (flag |= etorA.MoveNext()); i++)
            yield return etorA.Current;

        for(int i = 0; i < ratioB && (flag |= etorB.MoveNext()); i++)
            yield return etorB.Current;
    }
}
```

### Version 2

Almost same as version 1, but taking a variadic number of sequences.

```
public IEnumerable<T> Mix<T>(params KeyValuePair<IEnumerable<T>, uint>[] quantifiedSequences)
{
    var sequences = quantifiedSequences.Select(x => new { Etor = x.Key.GetEnumerator(), Quantity = x.Value });
    bool flag = true;

    while(flag)
    {
        foreach (var sequence in sequences)
            for(int i = 0; i < sequence.Quantity && (flag |= sequence.Etor.MoveNext()); i++)
                yield return sequence.Etor.Current;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `flag |= etorA.MoveNext()`.  You can just write `etorA.MoveNext()`.

Comment: You need keep track if last loop returned anything, otherwise we can't determine when both sequence are finished to exit the while loop.

Comment: flag |= x will always be true when flag is initialized to true. With minor flag issue fixed = clear and elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

this is my Linq solution :

For each element, assign an index then get the elements in the right order.

```
// for example. You can use with any type
IEnumerable<Int32> listA = new List<Int32>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
IEnumerable<Int32> listB = new List<Int32>() { 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110};

// you want 2 of list A and 1 of list B. You can change the values
Int16[] quantity = new Int16[] { 2, 1 };

IEnumerable<Int32> listC = listA.Select((e, i) => new  { element = e, index = (i / (quantity[0]) * (quantity[0] + quantity[1]) + (i%quantity[0]))})
                                .Concat(listB.Select((e, i) => new  { element = e, index = (i / (quantity[1]) * (quantity[0] + quantity[1]) + (i%quantity[1]) + quantity[0])}))
                                .OrderBy(e => e.index)
                                .Select(e => e.element);
```

The result is a `IEnumerable<Int32>` : 1, 2, 101, 3, 4, 102, 5, 6, 103, 7, 8, 104 ...

The difficult thing was to determinate the index. It work with what you want ({2,1}, {3,2}, ...)

For the first list :

```
index = i/(quantity[0]) * (quantity[0]+quantity[1]) + (i%quantity[0]) + 0
```

For the second list :

```
index = i/(quantity[1]) * (quantity[0]+quantity[1]) + (i%quantity[1]) + quantity[0]
```

Comment: Cool index transformation! In terms of usability it is not general enough to mix more than two enumerables. Problem with infinite enumerables. I didn't dw.